# Generating Eclipse project for Play 2 application with multiple modules?

Tags: eclipse, playframework-2.0, sbt, sbteclipse

From Activator UI, I generated a new play application [play-angularjs-webapp-seed](https://typesafe.com/activator/template/play-angularjs-webapp-seed). This application contains three modules `modules/db`, `modules/common` and `modules/users`.

When I generate an Eclipse project using `sbt eclipse`, and import it into Eclipse, I can see only `db` in projects list.

However there are two other projects `common` and `users` which are not being show.

What am I doing wrong? Please advise.

ADDITION:

I've been experiencing a similar issue with the [Gilt Groupe Play Application Template](https://typesafe.com/activator/template/activator-gilt-app). As I write, it is a multi-module Play 2.2 application that has 3 modules: core, web, svc.

It compiles just fine, and activator can run the application. The `sbt-idea` plugin generates the IntelliJ project files just fine. However, when I run `sbt eclipse` at the root directory of the template, the plugin only generates the Eclipse project files for core, but not for web or svc, even though the [build.sbt](https://github.com/gilt/activator-gilt-app/blob/master/build.sbt) clearly defines the modules.

Has anyone else experienced an issue with sbteclipse?

Comment: What directory did you run `sbt eclipse` in? Can you check `build.sbt` and make sure the projects are really defined within?

Comment: Does the app build fine inside Activator? It might be an issue with a missing dependency.

Comment: have you tried running `play eclipse` instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using activator, activator does not currently support more than one project, so that may be part of the issue.  You'll have to wait for the next big release of activator, as we're working on lifting this restriction.

Comment: That's unfortunate so looking forward to the next big release

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make make multiple modules for the [Play Akka Angular WebSocket template](https://typesafe.com/activator/template/play-akka-angular-websocket) and get `sbteclipse` to generate project files for each sbt project.

You will probably need to convert your `build.sbt` file into a `project/Build.scala` file.

Follow the instructions under [Adding a simple library sub-project](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/SBTSubProjects) to add a second module.

Comment: build.sbt vs. project/Build.scala shouldn't have any semantic difference.